# pass a vector (when defined in a struct) to a function

Tags: c++, struct

When I try and run this, I get the errors:

```
error C2676: binary '[': 'const Args' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator.

error C2088: '[': illegal for struct.

error C2660: 'Mergesort::get_uniform': function does not take 1 arguments.
```

How would I access the vectors args in my function?

Am I passing it incorrectly?

Note that I need to leave the function header as is.

Also, is there a way that I can leave the vector args in Args as an undefined size and define its size when creating Uniform?

Thank you for any feedback.

```
int get_sequence(double S[], int k, const Args &args); // function prototype

struct Args
{
string name;
vector<double> args;
Args() : args(2) {};
};

int main()
{

Args uniform;
uniform.name = dist_name;
uniform.args[0] = min;
uniform.args[1] = max;

distribution.get_sequence(S, k, uniform);

} // end main

int Mergesort::get_sequence(double S[], int k, const Args &args)
{

for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    S[i] = get_uniform(args[0], args[1]);
    cout << S[i] << " ";
}

return k;
}
```

Comment: Post a [MCVE] as usual please. `distribution.get_sequence(S, k, uniform);` doesn't make sense. What is `S` or `k` actually?

Comment: Please post some kind of correlation between the error messages and the code you posted.

Comment: This code is minimal in that I need to show all parts of my problem in order for the question to make sense. It is complete and verifiable as this is the exact compilation problem I am getting.

Comment: Your compiler told you which lines the error messages were referring to. You didn't relay that information to us. Not complete. The line number is the most useful piece of information for understanding a compiler error. Maybe we *can* figure it out without that, but why should we have to when you can just tell us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this instead:

```
S[i] = get_uniform(args.args[0], args.args[1]);
```

Because `args` is of type `Args` and it has a member `args` which is a vector. I'd suggest you name your structs and variables appropriately to avoid confusion.